# Android ListView not populating after Activity is restarted

Tags: android

The ListView is only populated the first time that the activity runs. After recreating the activity, the list is not populated. If I back out from the app and open it again, it doesn't work properly. However if I kill it from the tasks menu and open it again, it works. Also, the ArrayAdapter has different count (getCount) in the onResume and in the onImagesRetrieved. Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity implements ImagesDatabaseHelper.ImageDatabaseCallbacks {
    private static final int NUMEBR_OF_IMAGES = 10;
    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList());
        ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_titles)).setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ImagesDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this, NUMEBR_OF_IMAGES).retrieveImages();
    }

    @Override
    public void onImagesRetrieved(List<Image> images) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully got " + images.size() + " images", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        arrayAdapter.addAll(images);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see `Toast` every time, even when data not show?

Comment: Yes, Toast is displayed every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity implements ImagesDatabaseHelper.ImageDatabaseCallbacks {
    private static final int NUMEBR_OF_IMAGES = 10;
    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    List<Image> dataset = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataset);
        ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_titles)).setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ImagesDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this, NUMEBR_OF_IMAGES).retrieveImages();
    }

    @Override
    public void onImagesRetrieved(List<Image> images) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully got " + images.size() + " images", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dataset.clear();
        dataset.addAll(images);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually how I implemented it at first. Doesn't work, same behavior.

Comment: What is the size of `images` in `onImagesRetrieved` method?

Comment: 10, as it should be. When I debug I can see that the list contains the correct data.

Comment: Why do you think so? What default method of `ArrayAdapter` do you think is causing the issue?

Comment: When is `onImagesRetrieved` triggered? Is it always after `retrieveImages` call?

Comment: I said to use a custom adapter because your dataset is a custom array. the layout `simple_list_item_1` can only display a `TextView`.

Comment: Yes, `onImagesRetrieved` is always called after`retrieveImages`. 

I overrode the `toString` method of `Image` so Image works with the `ArrayAdapter` properly.

Comment: As far as I know, UI can only be updated from the main thread so AsyncTask will not work. However I did try to do what you said in the `onPostExecute` (which runs on the main thread) and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity implements ImagesDatabaseHelper.ImageDatabaseCallbacks {
private static final int NUMEBR_OF_IMAGES = 10;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
   ImagesDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this, NUMEBR_OF_IMAGES).retrieveImages();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ImagesDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this, NUMEBR_OF_IMAGES).retrieveImages();
}

@Override
public void onImagesRetrieved(List<Image> images) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully got " + images.size() + " images", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    arrayAdapter.addAll(images);
     arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, images);
    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_titles)).setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
   // arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
 }
```

Comment: I have tried creating and setting an adapter in the onImagesRetrieved but it has the same, broken behavior.

Comment: check now.The above expects that you have your arraylist ready.If you showing images then try with base adapter.

Comment: When `onImagesRetrieved` is called, the images parameter has the correct data. I am displaying Strings in the ListView.

Comment: Images? or Strings? Because i see your List is Image type.

Comment: Eventually it will be a custom view with an image and its title. For now I am only displaying the title. This works the first time I run it, so I don't think the problem is with the adapter type. I think the problem is that the `onImagesRetrieved` finishes before `onResume` after its first run. Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: are you using both portrait as well as landscape mode?

Comment: if Yes,Once try fixing to one way.either portrait or landscape and check it once.

Comment: I have one layout for horizontal and vertical orientation. The problem occurs whenever the activity is destroyed, on configuration change or if I close and reopen the app. I just found another weird thing. I will update the question.

Comment: I updated it. So after the app has ran at least once, pressing back to close it and opening it again doesn't work. However, if I kill the app from the tasks menu and open it again it works.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ArrayAdapter to a static field fixed this problem.